# What does for example 'elements[x]' do?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

So I just started learning python, my first programming language and I found this in CS Dojo's video and I don't understand this line '`given_list[i]`'. So we have a dictionary called '`given_list[]`' and a variable called '`i`'. If I combine this two together then what will happen?

```
given_list = [5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 10]

total3 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(given_list) and given_list[i] > 0:
    total3 += given_list[i]
    i += 1
print(total3)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, you have a *list* named `given_list`, and `given_list[i]` is just an indexing operation on that list. See the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for more information.

Comment: There's little reason to use a `while` loop here instead of a `for` loop. You don't care about the index `i` beyond retrieving a particular value of the list: `for x in given_list: ...` gives you each value directly without bothering with indices.

Comment: “*If I combine this two together then what will happen?*” Any reason you didn’t just try it out and see for yourself before posting here…?

Comment: The only reason to use a while loop here is if order matters since it will sum all elements that occur *before* a 0 value occurs. This could still be accomplished with a `for` loop and `break`, though.

Comment: @chepner - You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on your first venture in programming!

First off, `given_list` is not a `dictionary`, but rather a `list`. Think of it as a collection of items in one single variable. The `[]` is known as the indexing operator, which is the way we get elements from the list at a certain index. In python, and many other programming languages, the first element in the list has index 0. So in this case, the variable `i` is used as an index to loop over each element in the list and perform the calculations necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand it, atleast I hope so!

So because i = 0 it will start from the first (0) element which is 5, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

`given_list` is a list

`i` is a variable which happens to be a number

When you do `given_list[i]`, it will result in a value which is the element of the list (`given_list`), at index `i`.

Index starts at `0`, so the element at the first position is at index `0`, the element at the second position is at index `1`, the third at index `2`, etc.